# exponential to number conversion coding using xslt?

Tags: xml, excel, xslt-2.0

I have a column called adkey as shown in the figure. While I am converting excel to xml, I am getting  the xml tag in exponential forrmat. Eg.

```
 <AdKey>2.0160106001E10</AdKey>
```

but, I want an output as follows

```
<AdKey>20160106001</AdKey>
```

[image]

Is it possible to do this in xslt?

Comment: Did my answer helped with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should provide an example of the code (XSLT, XML, etc) that is producing the error.

Maybe you simply need to **cast the value to xs:decimal and then transform it to string**. Example:

```
string(xs:decimal(myValue))
```

---

Explanation: when transforming a float or double to string, if the value is not between 0.000001 and 1000000 it should be transormed using scientific notation. Extracted from [W3C XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators, **Casting to xs:string and xs:untypedAtomic**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#casting-to-string)

> - If SV has an absolute value that is greater than or equal to 0.000001 (one millionth) and less than 1000000 (one million), then the value is converted to an xs:decimal and the resulting xs:decimal is converted to an xs:string according to the rules above, as though using an implementation of xs:decimal that imposes no limits on the totalDigits or fractionDigits facets.
> - If SV has the value positive or negative zero, TV is "0" or "-0" respectively.
> - If SV is positive or negative infinity, TV is the string "INF" or "-INF" respectively.
> - **In other cases, the result consists of a mantissa**, which has the lexical form of an xs:decimal, **followed by the letter "E", followed by an exponent** which has the lexical form of an xs:integer. Leading zeroes and "+" signs are prohibited in the exponent. For the mantissa, there must be a decimal point, and there must be exactly one digit before the decimal point, which must be non-zero. The "+" sign is prohibited. There must be at least one digit after the decimal point. Apart from this mandatory digit, trailing zero digits are prohibited.